# Has there been any reference to the use of knowledge given from the Cytherians to the Enterprise-D?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Has there been any mention in canonical or non-canonical Star Trek about any useful use of the knowledge given by the [Cytherians](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Cytherian) to the federation in the episode [The Nth Degree](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Nth_Degree). This might have given them some scientific or technological edge in their wars against the Borg or dominion or any possible threats. Even though Picard notes that the knowledge they have been given "will take Federation scientists decades to fully analyze and appreciate", has there been any gained in the short term that helped the federation in any way?

Answer (score 4):

Other than the Nth degree the Cytherians are never mentioned again in the Star Trek canon.  There are references to their tech level in the DS9 technical manual, but beyond that there is nothing.

Picard notes that it will take Federation scientists decades to fully analyze and appreciate their technology.  If their technology was integrated into the Federation we have not seen it mentioned onscreen or in any of the official fiction.

Comment: Sorry Tyson, but this is no answer. I have followed your answers on many of my questions. They were are rather speculative and based on personal opinions rather than backed up by Canon or even non-Canon sources.

Comment: How about that?

Comment: Much better than before

Comment: http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Cytherian_probe
Even Memory Beta, which tends to be rather inclusive, doesn't mention anything about the Cytherians.

Comment: It's usually far more difficult to prove a negative.